# verifying property of inverse function of ln without using the fact that inverse is $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

Let $\phi(x) = \ln^{-1}(x)$. We want to prove that:

$\phi(x + y) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. We cannot use the fact that $\phi(x) = e^x$, just the fact that $\ln$ has an inverse (that is $\phi$) (which I was asked to prove in an earlier problem).

I thought about starting from the identity $\ln(xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$ and taking the inverse of both sides, but that left me with $xy = \phi(\ln(x) + \ln(y))$, and I didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: Ah, I misread your definition of $\phi$.

Comment: First, you need a definition of $\ln$.  Without that, of course you can prove nothing about $\ln$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know that $\ln(xy) = \ln x + \ln y$, just notice that

$$\ln \big(\phi(x) \phi(y)\big) = \ln \phi(x) + \ln \phi(y)  = x + y = \ln \phi(x + y)$$

where we have used that $\phi$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions. Now conclude that $\phi(x) \phi(y) = \phi(x + y)$ due to the injectivity of $\ln$.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close.  As a hint: we know that
$$
\ln[\phi(x)\phi(y)]=\ln[\phi(x)]+\ln[\phi(y)]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that:

$$\ln (\phi(x) \phi(y)\big) = \ln \phi(x) + \ln \phi(y)  = x + y = \ln \phi(x + y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assuming that $\ln$ is invertible, it is surjective. So given $x,y\in\mathbb R$, there exist $a,b\in\mathbb R_+$ with $x=\ln a$, $y\ln b$. Then
$$
\phi(x+y)=\phi(\ln a+\ln b)=\phi(\ln ab)=ab=\phi(x)\phi(y). 
$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a definition of $\ln$.  Without that, of course you can prove nothing about $\ln$.  I like the defnintion $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.  Then we can prove
$$
\int_1^{xy}\frac{dt}{t} =
\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_x^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}
= \int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t} + \int_1^{y}\frac{dt}{t}
$$
using a simple substitution in the second integral.

**added**
OK, second part, duplicating some other answers.  Suppose $\phi$ is a bijection (from set $A$ to set $B$) satisfying $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$.  Let $\psi$ be its inverse (from set $B$ to set $A$).  We want to prove $\psi(u+v) = \psi(u)\psi(v)$.  Now
$$
\phi\big(\psi(u)\psi(v)\big)\big)
= \phi\big(\psi(u)\big) + \phi\big(\psi(v)\big)\big)
= u + v = \phi\big(\psi(u+v)\big)
$$
But $\phi$ is injective, so this implies $\psi(u)\psi(v)=\psi(u+v)$.

Comment: I should have made it clear that we have this definition of ln, but we are asked to prove things about the inverse function of ln, not ln itself (in fact, the previous part of the question consisted of proving exactly what you said).

Comment: @4313 That would have been really useful context to include in your question.  Without that context, it is hard to know how to answer your question.